# dpkg warning : directory is not empty so not removed

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, mx-linux

While removing a package yesterday, I received warning like this :

`dpkg warning : directory is not empty so not removed`

When I checked the listed directory in the warning, I found that the directory is actually empty. That means dpkg successfully removed files inside that directory, but thrown out the warning, and not removed the directory.

Why does this occur ? Why dpkg give such warning even if the directory is empty ?

Comment: are you sure the directory didn't contain hidden dotfiles?

Comment: Oh..! My bad. It has a dotfile named .uuid That's why I was received the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Fox for pointing out this. I almost forgot dotfiles.

If the directory that is being removed has any files included that dpkg doesn't know about, it gives this warning. Sometimes, that directory may have system generated dotfiles. In those cases, we may receive this warning.